# Sorting issue with Apache camel

Tags: file, apache-camel

We have an application were we use the file component of apache camel. We implemented our own comparator to which we refer using #sorter. The file component reads files from four different folders and sorts them.
We have **maxmessagesPerPoll set to 0 and eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll set to false**.
The following described issue happens when we have somewhere between 1k to 5k files in the four folders combined.

Camel has apparently two threads Thread #1 and Thread#2, usually Thread #1 runs the sorting code and Thread#2 processes the files. But when there are between 1k to 5k files or more  even thread#1 starts processing which causes files to go out of order. See the logs in Listing 1 to see an example of how thread#1 and thread#2 are both processing the file.

FYI initial sorting for all 5000 files was done by thread #1, but during processing at times thread #1 contributes to processing the file too which results in files going out of order. This does not happen if the number of files are low like 200 eg. then only thread #2 processes the files.

**How can I keep the processing confined to just thread#2, is there a property that can be set?**

Listing 1

```
20200829 13:45:00.516 - [Camel (xyz) **thread #1** - file:///export/data/abc/xyz/zyz] INFO  a.b.c.Transformer - Processing started for file /export/data/abc/xyz/zyz//f/g/h../run/file1.xml
20200829 13:45:00.576 - [Camel (xyz) **thread #1** - file:///export/data/abc/xyz/zyz] INFO  a.b.c.Transformer - Processing completed for file /export/data/abc/xyz/zyz//f/g/h../run/file1.xml in 0 seconds


20200829 15:15:14.910 - [Camel (xyz) **thread #2** - Threads] INFO  a.b.c.Transformer - Processing started for file /export/data/abc/xyz/zyz/g/f/h../run/file2_XML
20200829 15:15:15.007 - [Camel (xyz) **thread #2** - Threads] INFO  a.b.c.Transformer - Processing completed for file /export/data/abc/xyz/zyz/g/f/h../run/file2_XML in 0 seconds
```

I tried the following suggestion -

Use maxMessagersPerPoll=1 and set eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false

as found here http://www.davsclaus.com/2008/12/camel-and-file-sorting.html
but that presents its own problems. Say there are 3000 files, it processes one file and then resorts the remaining files, which slows the whole process considerably since sorting takes like more then 45 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to this was to use the synchronous query option as described in File2 component documentation of apache camel. There will always be two threads. Once you use synchronous only thread #2 processes the files and not thread #1.
Additionally leave maxMessagesPerPoll to 0 and eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll to true.

I would have to say that documentation of camel is poor and not without its grammatical mistakes.